# Objects not getting saved in Parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

```
var Gift = Parse.Object.extend("Gift");
var Basketball = new Gift();

Parse.Cloud.define("GiftAddition", function(request, response){
  Basketball.set("p1", true);
  Basketball.set("p2", false);
  Basketball.set("p3", true);
  Basketball.set("p4", false);
  Basketball.set("p5", false);
  Basketball.set("p6", false);
  Basketball.set("p8", true);

  Basketball.save(null, {
    success: function(Gift) {
    // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
    alert('New object created with objectId: ' + Gift.id);
    },
    error: function(Gift, error) {
    // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
    // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
    alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
    }
  });
});
```

After `parse deploy`, I get

`Finished uploading files 
Not creating a release because no files have changed`

The latter only appears because I already tried uploading the code multiple times. The cloud code gets saved successfully, however the Data for the Gift class does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploying cloud code means you are uploading your code to the parse servers. You need to call them in order to run it. Try calling your code after you deploy your code.

```
      Parse.initialize("key", "key");     
    Parse.Cloud.run('GiftAddition', {}, {
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result)
      },
      error: function(error) {
console.log(error)
      }
    });
```

Try calling your cloud code like this from your html script.